`isomorphic-dompurify` with Angular 18 SSR runtime error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
I installed isomorphic-dompurify ^2.15.0 to my Angular 18 SSR application. It builds successfully with the standard DomPurify code, such as:
import DOMPurify from "isomorphic-dompurify";
DOMPurify.sanitize(dirtyHtml);

But at runtime, you will get the following error:
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /main.server.mjs:
|- TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\isomorphic-dompurify.js:19369:41)     
    at __require2 (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-2FDURXR6.js:51:50)
    at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\isomorphic-dompurify.js:22241:17)       
    at __require2 (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-2FDURXR6.js:51:50)
    at node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\isomorphic-dompurify.js:22648:16)
    at __require2 (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-2FDURXR6.js:51:50)
    at node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\isomorphic-dompurify.js:22662:9)
    at __require2 (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-2FDURXR6.js:51:50)
    at node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js (C:...\angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\isomorphic-dompurify.js:141933:21)

I found a similar, still open, issue here for Angular 15: Build error when using isomorphic-dompurify in angular 15 universal #203.

Which build tool did you use? WebPack or ESBuild?

If I understand correctly, esbuild, but uses vite on serve?. build builder: @angular-devkit/build-angular:application. serve builder: @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
